# Knockout, select all checkboxes and view list of select checkboxes

Tags: list, checkbox, knockout.js

I have a list with checkboxes, when I click at one of them, it is displayed in the`SelectedUsers`, works as it should, and checkboxes `data-bind="checked: AllChecked"` will checked too, but it should not be.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: SelectedUsers">
    <p>
        <span data-bind="text: userName" ></span>
    </p>
</div>
```

But, when I use `data-bind="checked: AllChecked"`, nothing is displayed in `SelectedUsers`, after that, when I click on some checkbox, all items are selected in the list and nothing is displayed in `SelectedUsers`

What's wrong?
example: http://jsfiddle.net/falkone/cr763bfj/

```
<div id="sideB">
    <div data-bind="foreach: AllUsers">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkedUser" data-bind="value: userName, checked:$root.selectedUserNames" />
            <span data-bind="text: userName" ></span>
        </label> 
    </div>
    Selected
    <div data-bind="foreach: SelectedUsers">
        <p>
            <span data-bind="text: userName" ></span>
        </p>
    </div>
        <label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: AllChecked" />Check all</label>
</div>
```

Knockout-3.3.0:

```
function User(data) {
this.userName = ko.observable(data.userName);
this.selected = ko.observable(data.selected);

}

var dataSource = [new User({userName: "Bill", selected: false}),
    new User({userName: "Andrii", selected: false})
    ];

function UsersViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.AllUsers = ko.observableArray(dataSource);
    self.SelectedUsers = ko.observableArray([]);

self.selectedUserNames = ko.observableArray([]);

self.selectedUserNames.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    var newSelectedUserNames = newValue;
    var newSelectedUsers = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(newSelectedUserNames, function(userName) {
        var selectedUser = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.AllUsers(), function(user) {
            return (user.userName() === userName);
        });
        newSelectedUsers.push(selectedUser);
    });
    self.SelectedUsers(newSelectedUsers);
});

self.AllChecked = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
        var firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst(dataSource, function(item) {
            return self.selectedUserNames() == false;
        });
        return firstUnchecked == null;
    },
    write: function(value) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(dataSource, function(item) {
            self.selectedUserNames(value);
        });
    }
})
}

ko.applyBindings(new UsersViewModel(), document.getElementById('sideB'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that is passed to the `computed` when `write` is called is not the username but a `true / false` boolean indicating the checkbox state.

Also, since `selectUserNames` is an `observableArray`, you need to `push()` the new `userName` and not to replace the entire array data.

Try this instead:

```
read: function() {
        var firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst(dataSource, function(item) {
            return self.selectedUserNames().indexOf(item.userName()) == -1;
        });
        return firstUnchecked == null;
    },
write: function(value) {
        if (value) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(dataSource, function(item) {
               if (self.selectedUserNames().indexOf(item.userName()) == -1)
                   self.selectedUserNames.push(item.userName());
            });
        }
        else {
            self.selectedUserNames.removeAll();
        }
    }
```

**Update (as per your comment):**

The `read` also needs to be changed to check for the existence of the first unchecked `userName` using `indexOf`:

```
var firstUnchecked = ko.utils.arrayFirst(dataSource, function(item) {
    return self.selectedUserNames().indexOf(item.userName()) == -1;
});
```

See modified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cr763bfj/4/)

Comment: It works, thanks.
Why when I click at one of the checkboxes, data-bind="checked: AllChecked" is checked too, it should not be like this.

Comment: It should be selected only  when all ckckboxes are selected

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have one more question left. When I chose one of the items and then chose "select all", the item that I chose before duplicates in the list, how can I correct this?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/cr763bfj/5/. I added `if (self.selectedUserNames().indexOf(item.userName()) == -1)` before actually `push`ing.